# Array as URL get parameter: URL-length restricton

Tags: arrays, url, post, get, url-parameters

As mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url-in-different-browsers) thread an URL has a length restriction. But what do I do when I have to submit an array of values via get parameters and can't ensure that the url doesn't exceed max length?

I know I could POST the request, but I want users to be able to bookmark/ cache the link.

Comment: Using a different data format might also help ... like f.e. JSON for simple arrays could reduce the length by a lot, I suppose ...

Comment: @CBroe you mean passing an JSON string as get-paramater?

Comment: Yes. You’ll have to decode it accordingly on the receiving end of course. But `foo[0]=bar&foo[1]=baz&foo[2]=blubb` vs `foo=["bar","baz","blubb"]` could make a difference, especially if `foo` was actually an even longer parameter name, and there are more values than the three in this example ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only possible solution would be to reduce the length of the URL as much as you can.

And if you can't reduce the amount of information that you need to transmit, try reducing the length of your GET parameters